# Selecting only visible layers exluding values that have not been symbolized?

Tags: arcpy

I have many mxd's and I want to capture the features that are visible in a specific layer and feed that to another data processing tool.  I wrote some code that gets a data frame extents and selects the features in the given extent. This seems to work pretty well.  However the issue that I need help with is figuring out how to only select what is displayed.  For example, a feature class might be symbolized by category, and have an " symbol value that is not checked, see screen shot.

Is there a way to select only the features from symbols that are visible?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Create a definition query to display only those that are symbolised - something like `STATUS IN ('Proposed Access Road', 'Existing Road')`.  Not symbolising something still makes them draw invisibly.  Filtering them out using a Definition Query will make them not draw at all (therefore not selectable)

Comment: that would work but each map has different symbols, there are over 200 mxd's so I need to find a way to dynamically produce a query or select by attributes based on the symbols. is there a way to get a list of values from the symbology that could then be plugged into a definition query or a selection by attribute query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arcpy you can determine the field and values used in a Unique Value symbol.  Using these values you could create a Definition Query, select all your features, then remove the query again.  This will mean the only selected features are those that are visible.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)

symField = lyr.symbology.valueField
symClassValues = lyr.symbology.classValues
otherValues = lyr.symbology.showOtherValues
exDefQuery = lyr.definitionQuery

if not otherValues:
    for x in desc.fields:
        if x.name == symField:
            print x.type
            fieldType = x.type
    if fieldType in ['SmallInteger', 'Double', 'Integer']:
        newclassvalues = tuple([float(x) for x in symClassValues])
    else:
        newclassvalues = tuple([x.encode('UTF8') for x in symClassValues])
    newDefQuery = "{} in {}".format(symField, newclassvalues)
    lyr.definitionQuery = newDefQuery
    print lyr.definitionQuery 

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, 'SWITCH_SELECTION')
lyr.definitionQuery = exDefQuery
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

You could probably also use the same logic to make Select by Attributes only select those that matched the symbology, rather than using the definition query.  This may be a safer route to try particularly if you already have some Definition Queries in place, as any existing Definition Queries will be ignored using my code above without a little modification to add to and then remove from the query.